# Redirect to random link from array

Tags: php, redirect

I have a script that is redirecting surfers to sections of my websites. For example when I send surfer to `script.php?car=bmw` it is redirecting surfer to `http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw`

This is how the script looks like:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "bmw" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw",
    "toyota" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota",
    "mercedes" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes"
);

$car = $_GET['url'];

header("Location: " . $array[$car]);

?>
```

Now I want to redirect surfer to random car, for example

```
"bmw" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x1","http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x3","http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x5",

"toyota" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/yaris", "http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/avensis", "http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/corolla",

"mercedes" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/e", "http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/s",  "http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/d"
```

So when I send surfer to `script.php?car=bmw` the script will redirect user to one of the random page from the bmw section.

Can I do this with one array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multi-dimensional array and array_rand() function. Try considering the code below:

```
$array = array(
    "bmw" => array("http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x1","http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x3","http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x5"),
    "toyota" => array("http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/yaris", "http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/avensis", "http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/corolla"),
    "mercedes" => array("http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/e", "http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/s",  "http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/d")
);

$car = $_GET['url'];

header("Location: " . $array[$car][array_rand($array[$car],1)]);
```

Instead of having one value for 'bmw', it now have array of value that can be randomized (array_rand() does that job for you).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_rand` for this -

Store them as -

```
"bmw" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x1,http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x3,http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x5",
```

And use -

```
header("Location: " . array_rand(explode(',', $array[$car])));
```

Comment: Great! This is correct construction of array? "bmw" => "a", "b", "c", "toyota" => "a","b","c", "mercedes" => "a","b","c" ?

Comment: Vote Up for the answer

Comment: I'm getting that error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/mywebsite.com/r.php on line 11

Comment: Missed the last `)`. :)

Comment: Lol looks like now it is redirecting but not to url from array but to index like mywebsite.com/0

Comment: Gene found solution, but thank you for your help, I need to learn mooooar :)

Answer (score 2):

you can restructure your array to include those subtypes in this case. Something like

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "bmw" =>array(
        'car1' =>  "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/car1",
        'car2' =>  "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/car2",
        'car3' =>  "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/car3",
        'car4' =>  "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/car4",
    ),
    "toyota" =>array(
        'car5' =>  "http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/car5",
        'car6' =>  "http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/car6",
    ),
    "mercedes" =>array(
        'car7' =>  "http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/car7",
        'car8' =>  "http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/car8",
    ),
);

$car = $_GET['url'];

header("Location: " . $array[$car][array_rand($array[$car]))];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
$array = array(
    "bmw" => array("http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x1","http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x3","http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x5"),
    "toyota" => array("http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/yaris","http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/avensis","http://www.mywebsite.com/toyota/corolla",),
    "mercedes" => array("http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/s","http://www.mywebsite.com/mercedes/d")
);

$car = $_GET['url'];

$rand = rand(0,count($array[$car])-1)

header("Location: " . $array[$car][$rand]);
```

Answer (score 0):

tôi đã làm như các hướng dẫn trên nhưng nó bị lỗi chuyển về: mywebsite.com/0
hãy giúp tôi với, tôi thực sự rất cần.
tôi đã làm như sau:

```html
<?php
$array = array(
    "bmw" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x1,http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x3,http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x5",
    "toyota" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x1,http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x3,http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x5",
    "mercedes" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x1,http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x3,http://www.mywebsite.com/bmw/x5",
);

$car = $_GET['url'];

header("Location: " . array_rand(explode(',', $array[$car])));

?>
```

Comment: thật tuyệt vời, tôi đã làm được. xin cảm ơn gợi ý từ các bạn rất nhiều

Comment: You need to write only english language